# Mysql write from one table to another while limiting many entries to 1

Tags: mysql

I have a table i want to merge in another one.
This table have entryID and activitiesID - the same entryID can have multiple activitiesIDs.

I want to move this data to another table which already have entryIDs
and an activitiesID empty column.

I would like to populate it:
each entryID to have only the last activitiesID from the first table.

Any suggestions?

thanks alot!

EDIT:

This code seems like is working for me:

```
UPDATE Individual
SET
Activities =(SELECT Indiv_status.activitiesID FROM Indiv_status WHERE
Individual.entryID=Indiv_status.IndividualID order by IndividualID desc 
limit 1)
WHERE Individual.entryID = (SELECT  Indiv_status.IndividualID
                        FROM   Indiv_status
                        WHERE  Individual.entryID = Indiv_status.IndividualID order by IndividualID desc limit 1);
```

Still need to check if the data comes correct but there is values from the second table now.

Comment: Can't you just insert it into the new table? What have you tried, please edit your question and indicate what you have tried, see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use the syntaxes [`LIMIT`](http://sql.sh/cours/limit) or [`MAX()`](https://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/max) or [`MIN()`](https://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/min).

Comment: Is there a question here? You say that _This code seems like is working for me_?